# Como apresentar botões dependendo do link da página

Tags: javascript, html, url, link

Olá, Preciso bloquear dois campos quando estão em um link específico. Como faço para bloqueá-los?

Obrigado.

```
<li class="VerificaUrl"><a href="a">Campo 1</a></li>
<li class="VerificaUrl"><a href="b">Campo 2</a></li>
```

```
<script>
function VerificaUrl(divid){
    var url_atual = window.location.href;
        
    if(url_atual == "homepage.com")
        document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso você não precisa passar o próprio elemento por parâmetro, pois a função vai analisar globalmente todos os elementos que contenham essa classe.

Se o seu objetivo for clicar no link que contenha esse método que você fez, e através do link clicado ele pegar o id do mesmo e remover a si mesmo, seria outra forma, mas não vejo muito sentido utilizar desse jeito.

O ideal seria que a classe `VerificaUrl` ficasse na própria tag `<a>`, mas dessa forma que está exemplificada abaixo, em teoria deve funcionar também. Segue:

```
function VerificaUrl(){
    let url_atual = window.location.href;
    let link = document.getElementsByClassName('VerificaUrl');
    if(url_atual == "homepage.com") {
        for(i = 0; i < link.length; i++)
        {
            link[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i < link.length; i++)
        {
            link[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

VerificaUrl();
```

Agora, se você quiser somente desabilitar o click e manter o botão a vista do usuário você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
function desabilitarFuncaoClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function VerificaUrl(){
    let url_atual = window.location.href;
    let link = document.getElementsByClassName('VerificaUrl');
    if(url_atual != "homepage.com") {
        for(i = 0; i < link.length; i++)
        {
            link[i].addEventListener('click', desabilitarFuncaoClick, false);
        }
    }
}

VerificaUrl();
```